# python syntax question - why isn't this code generating the expected output?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a complete python novice, learning how to code using some training videos (which have me using Python 2). In working through one exercise, I generated the below code to create a url dictionary. The video dictated that with the below code, inputting a blank input would lead to the break and end the sequence, but instead, I am taken to the "an error has occurred" message within the except code. This happens regardless of whether I type in an incorrect url or blank.  What have I done wrong in the code that has caused this?

Secondly, when I reach the stopproceed function in the code and type in anything other than 1, the loop returns an error message rather than continuing as I had intended.

Any help anyone can provide would be very helpful to a total newb who does not yet have the knowledge to troubleshoot for themselves!  Thanks!

```
while urltoread != '':  

    try:      
        urltoread = input("Please enter the next url to crawl ")  
        if urltoread == "":  
            print "OK, good loop!"  
            break  
        shortname = input("Please input a short name for this url "+ urltoread)      
        webfile = urllib2.urlopen(urltoread).read()  
        crawlweblinks[shortname] = webfile  
    except:  
        print "An error has occured, dummy",sys.exc_info()[0]  
        stoporproceed = input("Enter 1 to Stop, or enter anything else to continue")  
        if stoporproceed ==1 :   
            print "You got it!\n"  
            break  
        else:  
            print "On we go!\n"  
            continue  
    print "This line is inside the while loop"  
print "This line is outside the while loop"  
print crawlweblinks.keys()
```

Comment: your generic `except` clause is hiding the useful traceback error message

Comment: you should be using `raw_input()` in python 2 and casting to `int()`